# Check if a line goes through a polygon in any way

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I am making a program that find a path between 2 points on an image (soon to be frame of a video). What I have done is that I use Polygon objects to identify obstacles between the path, and with this polygon objects I go around as necessary. My code is as follows:

```py
SimplePoint = tuple[int, int]

def getPolygonsInWay(start: SimplePoint, end: SimplePoint, polygons: list[Polygon]) -> list[Polygon]:
    line = LineString([start, end])
    polygonsInWay = [polygon for polygon in polygons if line.crosses(polygon)]  # make sure line.crosses() doesnt return true if the starting point is on the polygon
    return polygonsInWay

def getPaths(start: SimplePoint, end: SimplePoint, polygons: list[Polygon], prev_points: list[SimplePoint] = []) -> list[list[SimplePoint]]:
    polygonsInWay = getPolygonsInWay(start, end, polygons)
    if not polygonsInWay:
        return [[start, end]]

    closestPolygon = closestPolygonToPoint(start, polygons)
    xyValsOld = closestPolygon.exterior.xy
    xyVals = []

    for i in range(len(xyValsOld[0])):
        xyVals.append((xyValsOld[0][i], xyValsOld[1][i]))

    xyVals = list(set(xyVals)) # remove duplicates

    polXVals = [val[0] for val in xyVals]
    polYVals = [val[1] for val in xyVals]

    okPoints = []

    for i in range(len(polXVals)):
        if start == (polXVals[i], polYVals[i]):
            continue
        if int(polXVals[i]) != polXVals[i] or int(polYVals[i]) != polYVals[i]:
            continue
        if (int(polXVals[i]), int(polYVals[i])) in prev_points:
            continue
        if closestPolygon not in getPolygonsInWay(start, (polXVals[i], polYVals[i]), polygons): #and closestPolygon not in getPolygonsInWay((polXVals[i], polYVals[i]), end, polygons):
            okPoints.append((int(polXVals[i]), int(polYVals[i])))

    paths = [[start] for _ in range(len(okPoints))]

    for i in range(len(okPoints)):
        point = (okPoints[i][0], okPoints[i][1])
        paths[i].extend(getShortestPath(getPaths(point, end, polygons, prev_points + [point]), point, end))

    return paths
```

At the moment, the only obstacles I am using are simple shapes such as rectangles, squares, circles, etc, and I will switch to using the video once everything works fine. The problem occurs when `line.crosses(polygon)` in the list comprehension in the function `getPolygonsInWay` returns false when the two parts are the diagonal of the rectangle. I have looked at the documentation but I cannot figure out what to use to make sure I catch this case properly, so I asked this question here.

**Edit:** As asked, an example polygon, start, and end points are below:

```
polygon = Polygon([[411, 182], [411, 335], [210, 335], [210, 182]])
start = (440, 35)
end = (90, 600)
```

With the code above, I get the following path after running `getShortestPath(getPaths(start, end, polygons, []))`:
`[(440, 35), (411, 182), (210, 335), (90, 600)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the method `line.within(polygon)` that checks if the line is inside the passed polygon. I do not know why I did not see it before but now I did. By doing `line.crosses(polygon) or line.within(polygon)` in the list comprehension if condition, I managed to get a path going around the rectangle. I will now test this with other basic shapes and then unlimitedly test it with what this is being used for.